# Which FOR loop is the best way to traverse through elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Which is the best way to traverse through a `<ul>` list and add a particual text to each `<li>` ??? Can i do with with a FOR loop like:

```
for (i=0; i<$('li').length; i++){
   ('li').eq(i).text(bla bla)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `text()` with callback it will iterate

```
$('li').text(function(i,v){
   // i - index of the element and v - old value 
   return 'bla bla';
   // -------^---- new value to update
});
```

For example :

```js
var con = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];
$('li').text(function(i) {
  return con[i];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: which is consider as best practice: your solution or the below
`var arr=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
var i=0;
$( "li" ).each(function() {
  $(this).text(arr[i++])
});`

Comment: @dios231 : I will prefer mine, since index will get as parameter

Answer (score 0):

In your example you dont need any loop whatsoever

```
$('li').text('blah blah')
```

will already update every `li` with the text

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. While `each()` has a simple syntax it is worse performance wise. Nevertheless you should select a DOM object one single time and then use the reference if nothing has changed withing the DOM. Otherwise jQuery will search the DOM multiply times every single loop

```
var elements = $('li');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
   elements.eq(i).text(bla bla)
}
```

Comment: So you think that calling `.eq(i)` each time in a loop will improve the performance? If you really want to, use something with pure JavaScript, i.e. `textContent`, `querySelector` and other stuff.

Comment: You don't apply any method to selected elements. Check the results: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop-using-eq/3. In my browser there is no difference at all.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. The loop itself is still faster. But I agree you will only notice a difference when having high loop numbers. I am not saying each() is bad or anything. I stated it is more important to cache variables.

Answer (score -1):

Nope, this is too heavy. Bare in mind that every time you call `$('li')`, jQuery looks for all `<li>` elements in the page and generates a collection out of them. As such, jQuery has a wonderful feature of method chaining and iterating, that will help to keep code fast. For iterating elements in a collection you can use a special [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method:

```
$('li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).text('element #' + i);
});
```

Or if you simply need to set the same text to all matching elements in a collection, use `.text` method applied to a selected jQuery object:

```
$('li').text('same text');
```